Is there any specific cause for the MySql communication link failure during rollback
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.
Error Code: 0
Whenever the quartz schedular tries to execute a job, the communication link fails with stackoverflow error.
I tried to increase the connection interval an timeout. But its already set to 8 hours.
MySQL database is also running smoothly without issue.
Also checked the MySQL errorlog, no active errror during the job excecution.
